# How to read data from a usb device with .net maui Androip app

Tags: .net, maui, usbserial, usbmanager

I would like to read and write data from a usb device. I am trying to use Android.hardware.usb Api. However I am new in .net maui. I looked some example but it is not understandable.
Could you plesae help this issue?

Trying to use Android.Hardware.Usb api but I don't how to use it.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You'll get much more helpful responses if you show us what you've tried and what specific problem you're having.  As written your question is very broad and not suited for SO's format